# Como passar um valor de parâmetro padrão dentro de um foreach no C#?

Tags: c#, loop, foreach

Caros amigos,

Como eu poderia passar um valor de parâmetro padrão dentro de um foreach?

Exemplo, dentro do meu foreach tenho um if que faz uma determinada comparação com um atributo da minha classe certo?. Mas por padrão no c# ao fazer get nos dados de um atributo preciso passar qual o ID da posição da lista quero receber tais dados (Ex: ListaEmpregados[**0**].getCodigo(), ListaEmpregados[**1**].getCodigo(), etc).

Mas meu problema é justamente esse quero fazer o get de todos os registros com aquele atributo, no caso não saberia a posição do meu ID exatamente (EX:Ex: ListaEmpregados[**N**].getCodigo(), ListaEmpregados[**N**].getCodigo() ).

Não sei se fui muito clara, mas existe alguma parâmetro 'padrão' ou algo no tipo que me ajude nesse caso? grata!

```
var ListaEmpregadosPorCodigo = ListaEmpregados.OrderBy(p => p.getCodigo());

foreach ( var codigo in ListaEmpregadosPorCodigo)
{
    int iCodigo = Convert.ToInt32(codigo.getCodigo());

    if (iCodigo == ListaEmpregados[].getCodigo())
    {
        //Código
    }
}
```

Comment: Se `p.getCodigo()` retorna o valor de um atributo não seria melhor criar uma [propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) para tal.

Comment: Não entendi a sua necessidade. Você está percorrendo uma lista no teu foreach. Tu quer pegar a posição atual do laço de repetição?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você poderia utlizar Linq para fazer essa operação, alem de  mais leve e mais clean code

tente

```
var items = ListaEmpregados.Where(x => 
                   x.Any(z => z.getCodigo() ==  x.getCodigo())
            );
```